# How do I pay a pro-forma invoice in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, finance

I'm using NetSuite. I want to buy some stock from another company.
However, they've sent me a pro-forma invoice. So I need to pay for it before they will ship it. Which is fine.

How do I process that?
What record do I create?
How can I tie that to a purchase order so I can book the items in when they arrive?

Seems like this is just an impossibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vendor prepayment to record the payment to vendor before shipment arrived.

Vendor prepayment can link to a Purchase order. So after purchase order is received and vendor bill is raised, the vendor prepayment will auto apply to the bill.

Vendor prepayment can be enabled from Setup -> Enable Features > Accounting Tab > "Vendor Prepayments"